# ¿Cómo puedo convertir dólares a euros en sql?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Me podrían colaborar con lo siguiente por favor,

Tengo un reporte que actualmente me muestra unos valores de facturación, estos valores ya se encuentran en dolares, pero deseo convertir uno de estos valores a euros, para dar solución temporal tuve que quemar los datos de esta forma.

--Indicando directamente en el campo el valor correspondiente en euros

UPDATE #PRORR_PO SET FOB_PROFORMA = '9391.76' WHERE FACTURA = 'SI2023010079'

Me podrían indicar por favor si conocen de alguna función que me ayude a realizar esa conversión sin tener que estar modificando la consulta del reporte. Muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Primero y principal necesitas una tabla de cotizaciones, ¿la tienes? indicanos el nombre y la estructura de la misma, luego tienes que establecer a que fecha se valorizaría, en el caso de una factura lo habitual es la fecha de emisión, luego simplemente es cuestión de llevar los dolares a la moneda del sistema y luego estos llevarlos a Euros.

Comment: Buen día Patricio, no, en realidad no la tengo.

Comment: Sin cotizaciones lo único medianamente razonable es cotizar todo a una sola fecha, define el coeficiente de conversión dolar/euro y haces directamente `FOB_PROFORMA = FOB_PROFORMA * coeficiente_dolar_euro`